# Angular chart js how to use formatter with Doughnut chart

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

i'm using chart js with angular js i want to show number or percentage in dought js using formatter but it did not work so  in html i do like this

```
  <canvas baseChart class="chart" [data]="doughnutChartData" [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
                      [options]="doughnutChartOptions" [chartType]="doughnutChartType"  
                      [colors]="doughnutChartColors">
                                       </canvas>
```

and i do this in chart js

```
public doughnutChartLabels: string[] = [
    'Demo',
    'Test',
    'Live',


  ];

  doughnutChartData = [];
  public doughnutChartColors: any[] = [
    {
      backgroundColor: ['#735A84', '#E76412', '#9BC311',],
    },
  ];

  public doughnutChartType = 'doughnut';
  public doughnutChartOptions: any = {
    animation: false,
    responsive: true,
   
    legend: {
      display: true,
      labels: {
        fontColor: '#9aa0ac',
      },
     
    },


    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
          formatter: (value, ctx) => {
              let sum = 0;
              let dataArr = ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
              dataArr.map(data => {
                  sum += data;
              });
              let percentage = (value*100 / sum).toFixed(2)+"%";
              return percentage;
          },
          color: '#fff',
      }
  }
  };
```

but the problem is that the chart was shown like i did not do the formatter and this is how the dought chart is shown

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your formatter function is working, only reason its not showing is because you never registered the plugin which is necesarry as stated in the [documentation](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#integration):

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);

const options = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        formatter: (value, ctx) => {
          let sum = 0;
          let dataArr = ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
          dataArr.map(data => {
            sum += data;
          });
          let percentage = (value * 100 / sum).toFixed(2) + "%";
          return percentage;
        },
        color: '#fff',
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js"></script>
</body>
```